# Java program how to read multiple Doubles in one line?

Tags: java

Alright,so I've got this assignment that requires me to have a method with a variable number of inputs as well as a string input. The inputs all have to be on one line in the scanner, and the method has to return the number of values entered,the average value,the max value,the min value,and the string that was entered.

This is an example of that the terminal window should look like.

> ```
> Please enter the name of the course: CourseNameHere
> Please enter the scores for CSC 201 on a single line and type a -1 at the end
> 71 02 81 44 84 17 38 11 20 05 93 -1
>
> The course name     : CourseNameHere
> Number of Scores    : 11
> The Average Score   : 42.37
> The Minimum Score   : 02
> The Maximum Score   : 93
> ```

The Average score has to be rounded to 2 decimal places(which I think I can handle) The only problem for me is getting the variable number of inputs to be scanned on a single line,and how to have the program count the number of inputs if I'm not hitting enter between the inputs. This is what I have so far.but I have no idea where to go from here. I can get it to ask for sequential values,but they aren't all on the same line

I would also like to know  what i would put as my return in the method? im new to java please help

this is  my program that calculates the code without reading it with one line but reading them in separate lines all i need is how to read them in the same line:

```
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of courses that you would like to\n" + "calculate the Average Score, the Minimum Score and\n" +"the Maximum Score: ");       // prompt the user to enter the number of courses for which the average, min and max neeed to be calculated.

    //create a scanner object to read from the keyboard
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //declares a new scanner called input to take input from keyboard
    int count = input.nextInt(); // read the user input and store it in the count variable
    input.nextLine(); //read the end of the line and throw it away
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      System.out.println("Please enter the name of the course: "); // prompt user to enter course name
      String courseName = input.nextLine();  // stores user input from keyboard into variable courseName
                System.out.print("Please enter a score for "+ courseName + " or type -1 to indicate\n" + "that there is no more score for this course: "); // prompt the user to enter a grade in the class
      double score = input.nextDouble(); // stores user input for score into variable double
      int numberOfScores = 0; // declare integer variable called numberofscored and set value to 0
      double total = 0; // declare a double variable called total and set value to 0
      double min = 100; // declare double variable called min and set value to 100

      double max = 0 ; // declare double called max and set value to 0
      while (score!=-1) // start while loop for when score does not equal -1
      {
          if ( score < min) // start of if statement 
          { min = score; 
          } //end of if //start of if statement
          if ( score > max) 
          { max = score;
          } // end of if statement
         total = total + score; // sets the value of variable total equal to itself + score
         numberOfScores++; // adds 1 to the variable numberofscores

         System.out.print("Please enter a score for "+ courseName + " or type -1 to indicate\n" + "that there is no more score for this course: "); // prompt the user to enter a grade in the class
         score = input.nextDouble(); // sets the value of score to the next input double from user
      }  
      double average = total/numberOfScores; // declare variable average and set value to total divided buy the number of scores
      System.out.println("The Course Name: " + courseName); //print a messege that shows the user the course name he entered
      System.out.println("Number Of Scores: " + numberOfScores); // prints a messege with the number of scores
      System.out.printf(" The average score: %.2f" , average); // prints a messege with the average score with only 2 decimal places
      System.out.println(); // goes to next line
      System.out.printf(" The Minimum score: %.2f" , min);// prints message with minimum score with only 2 decimal places
      System.out.println(); // goes to next line
      System.out.printf(" The Maximum score: %.2f" , max); // prints messege with maximum score with only 2 decimal places
      System.out.println();// goes to next line
      input.nextLine(); //read the end of the line and throw it away









    }
```

Comment: That's what `hasNextDouble()` is for.

Comment: "This is what I have so far" Sorry what do you have so far? I don't see any code

Comment: Well, seems you should show some code for people to trust you

Comment: i did take a look at it, this is the code i worked on but i need to change a little for it to read input from one line

Comment: you people are disrespectful! you see someone new and automatically assume i am lying and make fun of me? wth is wrong with you. i guess its true coders are scrubs with no social life and have no way to deal with people

Comment: @WatsDavies if you want my advice don't ever and never say "assignment" or "homework" no one going to help you , because they want you to try and try , after I saw your trying code I did write my answer so if my answer helped you and solve your problem please select it as an answer don't leave the question unanswered , good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do the work please ask me if you feel confused :

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

     System.out.println("Please enter the name of the course:");
     String course=input.next();

     System.out.println("Please enter the scores for CSC 201 on a single line and type a -1 at the end");
     int max=0;
     int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;

     int sum=0;
     int grade;
    that: while(true){
        grade=input.nextInt();

        if(grade==-1)
             break that;

         list.add(grade);
         sum=sum+grade;

         if(grade>max)
             max=grade;
         if(grade<min)
             min=grade;
     }
     System.out.println("The course name: "+ course);
     System.out.println("Number of Scores :"+list.size());
     System.out.println("The Average Score :"+(double)sum/list.size());
     System.out.println("The Minimum Score: "+min);
     System.out.println("The Maximum Score :"+max);
```

PS  : Integer.MAX_VALUE is a huge value maybe 100 is good if the limit of the grade is 100.

why using linked list ?

- because it's easy to store the values one by one .
- I can reach all elements when ever i want.
- also the method size of this list is the number of elements it has so I don't need a counter to count how many grades i have .
- also you can print them after that if you want because all grades now are stored in this list.
- if you don't need these grades in something next , you can ignore the list and do it without it .

Good luck .